# Change Windows 10 Font Size

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts

I don't know what happened but suddenly the font size Windows is using is larger. The font for content inside applications is not affected. I can find no setting to change it. This screen shot demonstrates the issue:

[image]

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to change the settings in `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalisation\Display` (default is 9 I think).

Comment: Did this issue only occur on Notepad?  what's edition of your Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

Change the size as the following steps:

**Settings -> System->Display**, under **Sale and layout**, **Change the size of text, apps, and other items** to what you want:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way

Go to Start menu => Control panel => Display

In there you can find "Custom size of items" - The first link use these display settings will directly fetch you to the Settings app where you can customize the size of the text, other stuff, and applications.

And - "Change only the text size" . In there you can set things